# Windows add new line on particular line number of file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a file with the below contents,

```
.
.
.   
:job details 
:emp details
:non tech emp details       #line number 75
:assist details             #line number 76
.
.
.
```

Am trying to add new entry on the line number 76 and expect output is below,

```
.
.
.   
:job details 
:emp details
:non tech emp details       #line number 75
:tech emp details            #line number 76
:assist details             #line number 77
.
.
.
```

Below is the batch script method am trying,

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "seventysixthLine=:tech emp details"
    (for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt) do (
        echo(%%a
        if defined seventysixthLine ( 
            echo(%seventysixthLine%
            set "seventysixthLine="
        )
    )) > C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt
```

and it doesn't work, getting below error,

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt.
```

Any help please..

Comment: you try to write to a file (i.e. overwrite, which means *delete*  a file) while at the same time you are reading it. Use a (temporary) outfile, you can later rename it to the original name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell you could do it like that:

```
$tmp = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt'
$tmp[0..75], ':tech emp details', $tmp[76.. ($tmp.Count -1)] | 
    Set-Content 'C:\Users\username\Documents\emp_details.txt'
```

**Attention:** You probably wan't to specify the *encoding* within the `Set-Content` cmdlet.

Comment: The statement which I want to contains `:` as well. Am getting below error `Unexpected token ':tech emp details' in expression or statement.`

Comment: Did you run this within PowerShell? I didn't got any errors.

Comment: Yes I ran on powershell and it was working with this fine. I tried to add with some more special characters like `=>` and `.` which doesn't work

Comment: Thats strange since its just a string what you define within  ':tech emp details'. I expect that to work.

Comment: I agree that was only the string I want to replace. Just to learn myself with different special characters. Am using powershell version 2 and this is what the string i tried `  :tech emp details => 25,`

Comment: It doesn't matter what you put into the string (except you have to escape single quotes). If you copy & paste *my* example and just replace the string, you still get an error?

Comment: It worked. Sorry there was some wrong thing printed when I did copy paste.

Answer (score 2):

read line after line, write the line to a new file; if the line is / contains your search line, add another line before processing the next input line:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "searchstring=:non tech emp details"
set "includestring=:tech emp details"
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
    echo(%%a
    REM alternative; use one of the two below lines:
      rem if "%%a"=="%searchstring%"  echo(%includestring%
      echo %%a|findstr /b /c:"%searchstring%" >nul && echo(%includestring%
)) > t.tmp
move t.tmp t.txt
```

Note: empty lines will be ignored (deleted). Can be adapted with some more code, when needed.

(I guess, it's ok to *not* rely on line numbers)